# Unable to sort products using liquid sort:

Tags: php, shopify, liquid

I'm doing some work for a family friend, they have a shop in iZettle which is using liquid templates. I'm trying to sort my products by weight but having no luck. I can't even log any data using `{{ variable | json }}`. I've not touched php for a long time and never used liquid so really struggling.

```
<ul class="tiles">
  {% assign sortedItems = (category.items | sort: 'item.quantity_unit') %}
  {% for item in sortedItems %}
    {{ item | json }}
    {% include tile-item.liquid %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Doesn't change the order at all. Don't get any output from `{{ item | json }}`. I don't know why the `item` data is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

What does {{ sortedItems | json }} returns?

you could try removing "()" from the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In regular liquid, this works : `{% assign sortedItems = (category.items | sort: 'quantity_unit') %}`.

But sadly your question is based on code nobody can see. The better option is to ask this question to iZettle support.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out iZettle completely restrict which liquid templating options you can use